# Как получить все ссылки со страницы регулярным выражением?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, python-2.x

Я хочу получить все ссылки со страницы. Для этого я использую такое регулярное выражение:

```
pattern = r"<a href=\"(.+)\">"
```

Но проблема в том, что мне нужно получить только значение первой группы, а не всего значения. При попытке вытащить значение таким образом:

```
all_href = re.findall(pattern, res.text)
```

Я получаю всю строку с ненужными мне `<a href...`.

Как получить только `\1` из текста?

Comment: На заметку: в общем случае данная регулярка вытащит не все ссылки

Comment: Да, про учет пробелов я забыл... Но суть не в этом.

Comment: Не нужно парсить HTML с помощью регулярок. Используйте специальные HTML-парсеры, например BeautiffulSoup. А так, кто межает из полученных строк вырезать нужное с помощью той-же регулярки.

Comment: @faoxis, замените `.+` на что-то менее жадное/более точное и будет все ок. Хотя бы `[^\"]+` возьмите.

Comment: Что будет, если в html-коде будут использованы одинарные кавычки? Что будет, если в тексте ссылки окажется кавычка? Можно придумать миллион примеров, когда регулярка не сработает.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @faoxis не только в пробелах проблема; andy.37 дело говорит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечая на сам вопрос — `findall` возвращает разные результаты в разных ситуациях:

- если в регулярке нет никаких групп (нет скобочек) — список строк, соответствующих регулярке;
- одна группа (одна пара скобочек — наш случай) — список строк, содержимого этих скобочек;
- две и более групп (много скобочек) — список списков (точнее, кортежей) строк с содержимым каждой скобочки.

Регулярка из вопроса для кода `'<a href="foo"></a> <a href="bar"></a>'` вернула мне `['foo"></a> <a href="bar']` — то есть жадно отожрала всё от самой первой кавычки до самой последней. Как правильно заметил Visman в комментарии, её надо сделать чуть более ленивой одним из вариантов:

- `pattern = r'<a href="(.+?)">'` (ищет до первого закрытия тега `">`; внутри ссылки могут быть другие кавычки)
- `pattern = r'<a href="([^"]+)">'` (ищет до первой кавычки; внутри ссылки кавычек быть не может)

Скорее всего, в случае данного вопроса оба варианта будут эквивалентны.

Тогда `findall` вернёт содержимое скобочек как положено:

```
>>> re.findall(pattern, res.text)
['foo', 'bar']
```

---

Как уже неоднократно отметили, парсить html регулярками — очень плохая идея; лучше воспользоваться BeautifulSoup4, с которым можно пропарсить всё намного точнее, качественнее и с учётом экранирования :)

Answer (score 7):

Как очень правильно заметил [@andy.37](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541300/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/541309#comment685227_541300) в комментарии, лучше пользоваться инструментами, которые специально предназначены для парсинга HTML, иначе вам придется проделать всю ту работу (обработка специальных случаев типа кавычек и другого, оптимизация по скорости и т.д.), которую уже проделали создатели данных модулей. IMO [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) самый популярный и удобный из известных мне парсеров:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

url='https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
print([link['href'] for link in soup if link.has_attr('href')])
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос :)

Comment: @andreymal, спорное утверждение... ;) Вроде должно "получить все ссылки со страницы", как и хотел автор вопроса...

Comment: Ну, формально вопрос был «Как вытащить только `\1` из текста?», а с неправильностью подхода мы уже сами пристали)

Comment: @andreymal, :-D

Comment: @andreymal, вы правы. Это действительно не ответ на вопрос. У меня задача такая, которую нужно решить регулярками, но за совет по библиотеке "спасибо" поставил. :)

Comment: @faoxis, ну тогда [мужайтесь](https://www.google.com/search?q=parse+href+html+nested+quotes&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr#pws=0&gl=us&q=problem+parse+href+html+(nested%7Cquotes%7Cbreaks)) ;)