# Регулярка, поиск ссылок

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

необходимо найти регулярным выражением все ссылки на сайте (в html коде).
Вроде написал `result_a = re.findall('href=(")\S+(")', text)`, но он находит только

```
('"', '"'),
```

хотя на [сайте](https://regex101.com/), он нашел ссылку в тексте

Можно конечно через XPath найти все ссылки на сайте, но думаю на это больше времени уйдет, да и писать разными способами как-то не очень

Comment: `re.findall(r'\shref="([^"]+)"', text)` - нужно то, что хотите получить, заключить в круглые скобки. А вы уверены, что вам регулярка нужна? Beautifulsoup получше будет.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew лишние элементы: #contact-seller,
#, tel:+491712169288,

Comment: `href` в каких элементах нужно найти? И с текстом в значении атрибута - любым?

Comment: `re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', text)`

Comment: @S.Nick такой же результат как и у виктора

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ну наверно в <a>,  текст у ссылки может быть любой

Comment: См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075568/3832970 - это ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew без библиотек для парсинга нельзя? Просто я рядом ищу телефоны регуляркой, не хотелось еще ради только ссылок строить дерево объектов

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew к тому же судя по коду, он скорее всего найдет только абсолютные ссылки, относительные не затронет

Comment: Ну, только потом будете думать, а что это всё значит... `re.findall(r'<a(?:\s+[^>]*?)?\shref="([^"]+)"', text)`. [См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/uARDEz/1). Но оно найдёт и `<a href="#"`.

Comment: Какие элементы? Приведите пример текста и желаемый результат.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://dropmefiles.com/Cklmr, как пример структура сайта, мне нужно написать универсальный шаблон, который бы искал ссылки на любом сайте

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541309/211923

Comment: @MaxU он довольно медленный, может лучше отдельно Lxml + xpath использовать?

Comment: @danilshik, приведите в вопросе пример или ссылку на страницу, которую вы хотите парсить.

Comment: @MaxU Предлагаю не мучиться и поступить, как следует: закройте вопрос как [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541309/211923). Сама формулировка - "*мне нужно написать универсальный шаблон, который бы искал ссылки на любом сайте*" - свидетельствует о том, что нужен полноценный парсер HTML.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, закрыл как дубликат ;)